# K & R function declaration

Tags: c, function, gcc

C expert  I'm trying to learn c and the compiler on my hp-ux uses K & R

I keep having

1. line 32: error 1584: Inconsistent type declaration: "Usage"
2. line 33: error 1705: Function prototypes are an ANSI feature
3. warning 419: Zero-length storage allocated for array argv

```c
int main(c,v) 
{
    int result; 
    int errno;
    int argc; 
    char *argv[];

    if(argc < 3 || argc > 3) {
        Usage(argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    system("clear");
    result = Search_in_File(argv[1], argv[2]);
    if(result == -1) {
        perror("Error");
        printf("Error number = %d\n", errno);
        exit(1);
    }
    return(0);
}

void Usage(char *filename) 
{
    printf("Usage: %s <file> <string>\n", filename);
    printf("%s version 1.0 \nCopyright(c) CodingUnit.com\n", filename);
}
```

thanks in advance for any input

Comment: Indentation................

Comment: `int main(c,v) ` => `int main(argc,argv) `

Comment: plus you're mixing ANSI and non-ANSI styles. K & R: this ship has sailed. Please use ANSI

Comment: The code you posted contains only 29 lines.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre there's no requirement to name the arguments to main `argc` and `argv`. `int main(int c, char*v[])` is perfectly legal, although I admit it looks a bit weird.

Comment: I agree, but if there are no protos for the args, they must match `argv` and `argc` defined in the code.

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre:  That would be `int main(c,v) int c; char **v; { ...` in K&R. `int c` can be omitted. The names do not matter, of course, but the parameter declarations should precede the first `{`. Declaring them locally, as in OP's code, will not work.

Comment: @AnT indeed. I admit my K&R is a bit rusty, I don't have fond memories of that time :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre No they don't. The `argc` and `argv` in the code are automatic variables, not parameter declarations (they are inside the function body). He has, in fact omitted declarations for the parameters altogether, so both are assumed to be int.

Comment: indeed! OP's K&R is rusty as hell too ... well, never mind, let's just _not_ use that

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre +100000, there's a reason why nobody uses K&R anymore!

Comment: K&R is outdated since 28 years. Get a modern compiler and use modern C. If that is something from your school, tell the teacher you will not get a job learing prehistoric C!

Comment: You are checking argc for < or > 3, but I don't see it being set to anything (checking uninitialized variable).  If you are expecting a user to pass parameters to main(), add the types to your variables in the declaration and use them.  Also, argv is uninitialized so maybe that is what Usage() is complaining about.

Comment: Knowing pre-ANSI C could be a valuable skill in the field of software archaeology. Are you asking how to use K&R C, or how to enable modern C on your HP? These are two totally different career choices.

Comment: Put 
    void Usage(char *filename); 
above main.

Comment: The default (K&R) compiler on HP-UX is only suposed to be used to compile the kernel for reconfiguring it.  It is not intended for software development.  HP has a perfectly good modern C compiler; it just isn't shipped by default (I assume you have to pay for it).  It used to be possible to build GCC with the default compiler; since it now requires a C++ compiler, that's no longer true.  Or, at least, you'd have to install GCC 4.x, and then compile GCC 7.x (7.1 released 2017-05-02, yesterday as I type) with that.

Comment: Incidentally, the `int errno;` needs to be `extern int errno;` — or better, `#include <errno.h>`.  But even that is fraught; it is most often a macro that wraps a function call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good Lord, the HP-UX C compiler *still* defaults to K&R?!  That was sort of excusable 20 years ago, now not so much.

To make this compile as K&R (pre-ANSI) C, change your function definitions as follows:

```
int main( argc, argv )
  int argc;            /* move declaration of argc and argv from the */
  char **argv;         /* body of main to here */
{      
  /* leave everything else the same */
}

int Usage( filename ) /* void was introduced in C89, don't think it existed in K&R */
  char *filename;
{
  /* leave the same */
}
```

Having said that, the *right* answer is to use proper function prototypes and to find the command-line option that puts the compiler in C90 (or later) mode, or use `gcc`.  **Nobody** should be using K&R-style function definitions in new code.

**EDIT**

Note that, under K&R and C89/90, if the compiler sees a function *call* before it sees a declaration for that function, it will assume the function returns `int`.  Since I've declared `Usage` to return `int` above (as there was no `void` type in K&R), this code will compile under K&R.

If I had defined `Usage` to return any type other than `int`, the compiler would complain about a type mismatch between the *implied* declaration and the function definition.

As of C99, implicit `int` typing is no longer allowed, so all functions must be explicitly declared or defined before use.

Comment: 20 years ago I was using HPUX and I never had to use K&R. I believe there's a --ansi flag to the cc HP compiler.

Comment: The "leave everything else the same" comment in `main` is incorrect. He needs to remove the declarations of argc and argv in the function body.

Comment: @JeremyP: Edited to make that clear.

Comment: Have an upvote. By the way, you are correct that K&R had no `void` type.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Yeah, that's a small part of why I hated working on HP-UX in the '90s.  Every other compiler, whether `gcc` or the platform's bundled C compiler, was defaulting to C89/90.  But not UP-CHUX, no, they were *special*.

Comment: Back in the 90's, I worked for a company that had a cross platform product and the coding standards insisted we used some crazy macros to declare function prototypes so that the code would compile in both ANSI and K&R C. At the time we compiled everything for whatever platform with `gcc` so it was just an annoying waste of time.

Comment: the only good way to fix the HPUX problem is with a can of gasoline and a lighter and try to get the insurance check

Comment: thank you guys for your input the sever I'm working on only has cc. planning to install gcc will see if that will solve some of my issues. in the main time when I made the change for usage function I got Redeclaration of "filename" hides formal parameter

Comment: @Driven: make sure the full declaration of the parameter comes before the opening `{` of the function body, as in my example above.

Comment: thanks for your help it worked